# Slow hard drive with possible bad sectors

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive

My computer recently started to stutter a bit lately and one of my Seagate hard drive became really slow when opening folders, running programs from the drive etc., ultimately ending with the computer restarting. Upon reboot it went right into the Windows 10 chkdisk on boot. It was very slow as well, so I ended up leaving it over the night. Before I left the computer I saw there was a bad sector mentioned. Next day I was a bit more relieved when I saw the logon screen, and I found the hard drive in Windows explorer. First thing I did was to start copying everything, but the transfer speed is very slow. It jumps to between 1 and 3 mbps, until it drops down to 0 again. In one day I was able to copy around 20 gb.

With the hard drive being this slow I guess it's a sign of the drive slowly failing. I checked the computer management, and it seems the disk has changed from Basic to Dynamic for some reason I don't know after running chkdsk.

I would appreciate some advice on what's the best idea right now. My first thought is to leave the computer on and just keep copying files. Or is it better to take breaks every now and then? And with the disk being 1.8 TB and with this speed it will probably take a month until everything is copied, and I'm a bit afraid the drive will fail before it's completed. And will the heat produced from the HDD possibly have a bad impact on its already failing condition? Or is there better ways to take backup, or are there other possible causes for the hard drive being slow? I have tried swapping cables and hard drives to check.

Comment: Is it a pc or laptop? If a PC open the case and point a small fan at the hard drive, copy smaller file batches.

Comment: @Moab It's a workstation. You mean to cool it?

Comment: Yes, take the cover off and point a small fan on the hard drive area.

Answer (score 1):

First, use any of the free disk **imaging** utilities, such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) to copy *the whole disk*. If possible, boot from USB rather than the HDD, to avoid writing to the disk! Reflect, for example, can make a boot USB drive using [WinRE (AKA WinPE)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference). This has some large benefits:

- Imaging applications use direct disk I/O, rather than copy a file at a time. On a *healthy* HDD, I find imaging 2 TB of files takes about 3 or 4 hours, and about the same additional time to verify the image (Important! A bad image is not very useful).
- Since the *entire* disk is saved, you can restore that image to a drive of the same size or larger, and have your system working as before.
- If you're booting from USB, there's no need to write to the bad HDD, possibly causing more damage.

*Caveats*:

- If the disk has many bad sectors, there will be many retries to read each such sector, slowing imaging.
- If a complete image cannot be made and verified, try to mount the partial image and view files; it might still salvage most of the disk.

If there are files you cannot salvage, that you *must* have , get an estimate from a commercial data recovery service, but expect it to be costly.

In the future, make periodic images of your HDD to avoid trying to salvage it *after* there's an issue.

Comment: If you are comfortable at the Linux command line, ddrescue is a very good programming to bit copy a failing disk - particularly as it can be restarted and is designed specifically for failing disks

Comment: I tried using Macrium Reflect. It got to about 80% of the analyzing until it said I have to run a chkdsk. So I started a chkdsk. It's now in about 90% in Stage 2 of 3, but says 0% total and ETA 999 hours. So I'm thinking maybe best would be to cancel it, run some Linux software like Safecopy or ddrescue to get out as much data I can. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the slow speed and size of drive, you may wish to take it to a disk repair agency to see if they can copy the files, or help you in any other way.

Just leaving it to copy in the state it is in will (very likely) accelerate the damage and then subsequent failure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I'm considering this option now. Do you they might be able to get some data out? Last time it was connected I saw the drive in computer management but wasn't able to see it in explorer. Maybe too many bad sectors?

Comment: Probably too many errors and that is why the suggestion for a repair agency. You need to ask them to assess the drive

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to in such a situation is to get SMART parameters.
When you do this under linux using smartmontools that does not stress the drive too much.

You most likely have broken sectors. As the source of dammage is unknown the best solution is to use a fault-tolerant copy tool on sector level.

Copying files on file system level is stressful. Using the Macrium software as a duplicating tool is not a good idea because it has not been designed to handle bad sectors.

ddrescue (Linux-based) is the specialist.

Running chkdsk is a bad idea as well.
This is something you can do with your second duplicate after copying the faulty source to a target and copying the physically healthy target to another drive for test and play purposes like using chkdsk.

Comment: I tried ddrescue but the process was very slow and it ended up failing.

Comment: Did you use GNU ddrescue? What does "fail" mean? What did the progress indicator say? Did you use the ddrescue logfile feature?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I ran it from Ubuntu from an USB. The transfer speed was on an average of 1.5 mbps and I was able to transfer 5-10 gb until it failed. When I rebooted chkdsk started to run on my destination drive for ddrescue. I remember I set log file to be saved to the USB but I can't find it.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "failed"? What happened?

Comment: It stopped. I think it was because of bad sectors. I think it said it was over 10-20 mins since last successful read. I was looking for the log file but didnt find it where I pointed it to. But I'm afraid more serious stuff is wrong than just bad sectors. When I booted the computer with the hdd it didnt always find it in BIOS or Windows. I even had to format the destination drive after the attempt of ddrescue.

Comment: The command I ran was something like (sda2 and sde1 being the partitions and root being the USB) : ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda2 /dev/sde1 /root/recovery.log

Comment: When using a healthy target drive to duplicate a drive there is no need to format the target. If the duplicate process is stopped the the target is incomplete and may certainly contain empty sectors where the corresponding source sectors had been unable to read but there is no reason to format. That was a big mistake. After all I would recommend you using a professional recovery service now.

Comment: And it would probably have been a better idea to make an image rather than duplicating to partition? Running ddrescue again may probably do more harm now? Yeah, I guess I will seek professional help for it. Thanks alot. I've learned a lot.

Comment: Imaging is better that duplicating on file level. And if you knew for instance what partition to ignore you could restrict imaging to an area of your disk as partitions are continuous spaces on disk. That would lessen the stress on the drive even more.

Comment: With duplicating I meant I ran ddrescue without the img option,but rather partition to partition. Somehow after chkdsk ran first time the hdd seemed to get partitioned into a dynamic partition. I guess that is because it tries to leave out bad sectors maybe? I'm a little curious about trying ddrescue again but with making a image file instead, but I'm thinking about everything that could make things worse. Maybe theres another reason its going slow? Maybe I already did too much harm to it already running it once.